# Customizing SDCAlertView

Tags: swift, ios9, uialertview, sdcalertview

I am using the SDCAlertView Cocoapod and am attempting to customize the alertview and actionsheet so that the cornerradius, actionViewSeparatorColor, default textcolor and .Destructive textcolor are changed as seen in these images:

- [image of alertview](http://postimg.org/image/ixh9l0i5p/)
- [image of actionsheet](http://postimg.org/image/a16hh2rjh/)

I have tried creating a type as suggested in the github docs:

> If you are looking for more customizations, create a type that conforms to VisualStyle and use visualStyle on the AlertController instance. You can also subclass DefaultVisualStyle for a set of default values that you can then override as needed.

But have not had any luck.  I was hoping you good provide an example on how to do this?

These are the three things I wish to override in the pod:

```
  VisualStyle protocol extension:

   public var actionViewSeparatorColor: UIColor { return UIColor(red: 142/255.0, green: 54/255.0, blue: 65/255.0, alpha: 0.4) }


   public func textColor(forAction action: AlertAction?) -> UIColor {
        if action?.style == .Destructive {
            return Style.maincolor()
        } else {
            return Style.mainTextColor()
        }
    }

DefaultVisualStyle Class:

    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            return 6
        } else {
            return self.alertStyle == .Alert ? 6 : 4
        }
    }
```

To answer your question, in the comments, I have played around by attempting this:

```
import UIKit
import SDCAlertView

public class AlertViewStyle: VisualStyle {

        private let alertStyle: AlertControllerStyle
init(alertStyle: AlertControllerStyle) { self.alertStyle = alertStyle }

            public var width: CGFloat { return self.alertStyle == .Alert ? 270 : 1 }

            public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
                if #available(iOS 9, *) {
                    return 6
                } else {
                    return self.alertStyle == .Alert ? 6 : 4
                }
            }

            public var margins: UIEdgeInsets {
                if self.alertStyle == .Alert {
                    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
                        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
                    } else {
                        return UIEdgeInsetsZero
                    }
                } else {
                    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
                        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 10, bottom: -10, right: 10)
                    } else {
                        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: -8, right: 10)
                    }
                }
            }

            public var actionViewSize: CGSize {
                if #available(iOS 9, *) {
                    return self.alertStyle == .Alert ? CGSize(width: 90, height: 44) : CGSize(width: 90, height: 57)
                } else {
                    return CGSize(width: 90, height: 44)
                }
            }

            public func font(forAction action: AlertAction?) -> UIFont {
                switch (self.alertStyle, action?.style) {
                case (.Alert, let style) where style == .Preferred:
                    return UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)

                case (.Alert, _):
                    return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)

                case (.ActionSheet, let style) where style == .Preferred:
                    return UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)

                case (.ActionSheet, _):
                    return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
                }
            }



            public func textColor(forAction action: AlertAction?) -> UIColor {

                if action?.style == .Destructive {
                    return Style.mainColour
                } else {
                    return Style.mainTextColour
                }

            }


         public var actionViewSeparatorColor: UIColor { return UIColor(red: 142/255.0, green: 54/255.0, blue: 65/255.0, alpha: 0.4) }


        }
```

I then tried to bring it to life when creating an alert in a viewcontroller by:

```
 let alert = AlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let alertStyle: AlertControllerStyle = ???

        alert.visualStyle = AlertViewStyle(alertStyle)
```

I was just playing about.  I tried a whole bunch of different things to try and get it to compile with no luck.  I see from the SDCAlertView github issues someone has successfully customized the alert and action sheet views.  Based on the above code, do you have any suggestions on how I should proceed.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much,

Alexis

Comment: Could you please provide some actual code that you've tried? As it is this wouldn't work because not only do you have to override the visual style, but you also have to then assign that visual style to the alert controller.

Answer (score 0):

I figured part of it out with the help from a colleague. Creating the AlertViewStyle class is correct.

Then when you are creating an alert in a viewcontroller, you do the following:

```
 //Create an alert
    let alert = AlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

 //And declare its style
        // for alertviews
        alert.visualStyle = AlertViewStyle(alertStyle: .Alert)

       // for actionsheets
        alert.visualStyle = AlertViewStyle(alertStyle: .ActionSheet)

 // Add actions and present...
        alert.addAction(AlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default))

        alert.present()
```

This changed everything for action sheets, but for alert views I am still not able to change the title and message labels' font or color.  If you have any advice on how to access and customize this - that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Title and message fonts and colors can be changed by using `NSAttributedString`s. The visual style doesn't provide a way to customize those.